# order_by fixNum, integer... mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have an object with attribute `impressionist_count`. `impressionist_count` is a `Fixnum`.

```
object.impressionist_count
# => `20`, `1000`, `26`, etc.
```

I want to sort all my objects in descending order, but it does not work, something like:

```
Objects.order_by(:impressionist_count, :desc)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.desc()`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html):

```
Objects.desc(:impressionist_count)
```

Or you can use `.order_by()` if you wrap using arrays like this:

```
Objects.order_by([[:impressionist_count, :desc]])
```